# "export 'createApp' was not found in 'vue'

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, vuex

Im a newbie vuejs dev and im trying to use vuex for state management but encounter an error. Here is the code:

```
**main.js file**

    import { createApp } from 'vue';

import router from './router';
import store from './store/index';
import App from './App';
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify';

const app = createApp(App);

app.use(router);
app.use(store);
app.use(vuetify);
app.mount('#app');

  **error**
```

WARNING  Compiled with 4 warnings
warning  in ./src/main.js

"export 'createApp' was not found in 'vue'

warning  in ./node_modules/vuex/dist/vuex.esm-browser.js

"export 'inject' was not found in 'vue'

warning  in ./node_modules/vuex/dist/vuex.esm-browser.js

"export 'reactive' was not found in 'vue'

warning  in ./node_modules/vuex/dist/vuex.esm-browser.js

"export 'watch' was not found in 'vue'

Answer (score 3):

The errors (and the [vuejs2](/questions/tagged/vuejs2) you've added to the question) seem to indicate that you're running Vue 2, but your code is actually using Vue 3's API.

The simplest solution that would require the least change is to install Vue 3 in your project:

```sh
npm install --save vue@3
```

Comment: or use the vue2 api..... eg  https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html

Comment: upgraded it but got another bug ` Error: [VuetifyLoaderPlugin Error] No matching rule for vue-loader found.
Make sure there is at least one root-level rule that uses vue-loader and VuetifyLoaderPlugin is applied after VueLoaderPlugin. `

Comment: There's not enough context to resolve that issue. It sounds like you attempted to setup your project by hand. I recommend using [Vue CLI](https://cli.vuejs.org/) to scaffold a new project. Adding Vuex, Vue Router, and Vuetify is easy with that tool.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need to use like that way:

```
const app = Vue.createApp({/* options */})
```

or

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
const app = createApp({
    // root instance definition
});
```

And main.js is not suitable for that definition, I guess.

Reference from Vue [document](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/instance.html#creating-an-application-instance)